# NRPE agent on remote sever not starting with nrpe_user

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to start nrpe agent on remote server. As per the configuration (nrpe_user=nagios) nrpe must run under **nagios** user like:

```
root@workingIP:/etc/nagios$ ps -ef|grep nrpe  
nagios    3748     1  0 Apr25 ?        00:00:06 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -d
```

But its starting under **ubuntu** user:

```
root@IssueIP:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# ps -ef|grep nrpe                  
ubuntu    8900     1  0 Apr20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -d
```

Please help me to solve this if anyone else faced the similar issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit init script for nrpe service.

In Ubuntu it's usually /lib/systemd/system/nrpe.service or /usr/lib/systemd/system/nrpe.service. Sometimes init script also lays in /etc/init.d/ folder

Change user and group in init script and then reload systemctl configuration. After that you'll can start your service from another user

Comment: Thanks for your valuable replay @Anton Makovetsky. Will try it tonight...